# Operation has timed out when sending email using asp.net and smtp.gmail.com

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to send emails using my asp.net application. Here's my code:

```
string smtpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"].ToString();
            int smtpPort = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPort"]);
            string smtpUser;
            string smtpPwd;

            if (administrativo)
            {
                smtpUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpUser"].ToString();
                smtpPwd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPwd"].ToString();
                //smtpUser = "licitacoeslic@gmail.com";
                //smtpPwd = "liclicitacoes";


            }
            else
            {
                smtpUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpNoReplyUser"].ToString();
                smtpPwd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpNoReplyPwd"].ToString();
                //smtpUser = "licitacoeslic@gmail.com";
                //smtpPwd = "liclicitacoes";
            }


            bool smtpSslEnabled = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpSslEnabled"]);

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpClient.Host = smtpServer;

            if (smtpPort > 0)
                smtpClient.Port = smtpPort;

            if (smtpUser != String.Empty)
                smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUser, smtpPwd);

            smtpClient.EnableSsl = smtpSslEnabled;

            //transforma a mensagem de e-mail em html para habilitar o uso do logo
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(de, para, assunto, texto);
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

            smtpClient.Send(mm);
```

I've tried 465 and 587 as port numbers, exchanged my credentials because apparently, the older ones in my web.config don't exist anymore, pinged smtp.gmail.com via cmd and it's working properly. EDIT: it seems that you need to use a gmail account with this method. And yeah, i'm using one.

And the funny thing: the same code, worked yesterday. Is there anything i'm missing here?

EDIT: here's what happened after some testing:

1) I've tried to use my private gmail account to see if the same timeout exception would be thrown. It worked. The gmail account i created to be part of the credentials doesn't work.

2) Now, when i tried to see if the gmail account i created worked, i got this exception:

5.4.5 Daily sending quota exceeded. n4sm29019478yhc.13 - gsmtp

So, what? I have a limit of emails i can send per day?

Comment: There is a limit https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, what? I have a limit of emails i can send per day?

About this, Gmail has a spam protection (and that's usually good). After sending some emails, the Gmail requires you to login in Gmail account (site) and the site will ask to you enter a captcha. After the captcha is sent, then you can keep sending emails, but you still have a limit to send emails per day.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
     UseDefaultCredentials = false,
     EnableSsl = true,
     Timeout = 20000,
     Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someguy", "password")  // gmailid is someguy@gmail.com
};
```

May be some your config settings are incorrect

Comment: I'm using the same parameters that you used. The only addition was the timeout. But the exception was thrown faster with this value. It didn't work.

Comment: No need to set the timeout, i was just checking it and set it to 20 seconds, you can leave it. But thats just about it. Other thing you may need is, the number of emails you can shoot using the google smtp. It is restricted to 99 i guess.